# libmcrypt.dll and php_mcrypt.dll not found in windows

Tags: php, dll, xampp

I installed php using xampp. But php_mcrypt.dll not found in the php/ext folder. libmcrypt.dll also not found in php folder. How can I install libmcrypt.dll and php_mcrypt.dll?

Below is the screen capture of the two files that are not found:
[image: php_mcrypt.dll not found]
[image: libmcrypt.dll not found]

Comment: if you using php 7, read this http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php, may help you..

Comment: @Juragan I am using php 5, is there any other way to install it?